# Setting RHEL default yum repositories

Tags: redhat, yum, rpm

I've been tasked with setting up PHP on a RHEL 6 server.

running `yum install php` gives me the following output:

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager 
Updating certificate-based repositories. 
Setting up Install Process 
No package php available. 
Error: Nothing to do
```

There are two files in `/etc/yum.repos.d`:

**redhat.repo**:

```
#
# Certificate-Based Repositories
# Managed by (rhsm) subscription-manager
#
```

**rhel-source.repo**:

```
[rhel-source]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch - Source
baseurl=ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/$releasever/en/os/SRPMS/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release

[rhel-source-beta]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever Beta - $basearch - Source
baseurl=ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/beta/$releasever/en/os/SRPMS/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-beta,file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
```

I've looked around and it seems that this is not the default configuration.  I want to restore the RHEL6 repositories (which should include PHP 5.1, I believe).  What can I do?

**(updated in response to @ewwhite)**:

```
# rpm -qi php
package php is not installed
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
repolist: 0
```

Comment: What is the status of your subscription to the RHN?

Comment: Wups.  It looks like this system's subscription is not valid (`rhn_check -v` echoes `ERROR: unable to read system id.`).

Comment: Nice to know you've found the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHP is probably already installed on the system. Please check with:

```
rpm -qi php
```

You won't find much in the `/etc/yum.repos.d/` tree on a RHEL system. You can view your subscribed repositories with `yum repolist`.

Also, please make sure the server has a valid Red Hat subscription and entitlement.

Comment: I've added the results of the queries you suggested.

Comment: Did you register your system with Red Hat?

Comment: No, I didn't.  (Not my system.)  Could you add that this may be due to an invalid subscription in your answer so I could accept it?

Comment: @bdares Sure. That's updated.

Answer (score 4):

Your system doesn't appear to have a valid entitlement.

[Register the system](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/registering-cmd.html) and [assign it an active subscription](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sub-cli.html) to gain access to the Red Hat software repositories.

P.S. RHEL 6 ships with PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Set enabled=1 in the repo file.

Comment: More detail will help make this a better answer.